# Getting Wikipedia page view statistics

Tags: wikipedia

I'm trying to collect time series data over the last five years on Wikipedia page view statistics for a particular webpage ("Bitcoin").  I found this site to be useful: http://stats.grok.se for getting this data.  Two issues:

1. The website triggers an "internal server error" error whenever 2016 is selected as a year for which to obtain data.
2. Is there an existing tool that can put this output in more usable form, such as a .csv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about stats.grok.se as it doesn't appear to live on a wikimedia production or labs server. But there's an API provided for page view statistics starting July 2015:

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Pageviews_data/get_metrics_pageviews_per_article_project_access_agent_article_granularity_start_end

E.g., daily page views to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin over the past year: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia.org/all-access/all-agents/Bitcoin/daily/20151105/20161105

all-access = desktop+mobile-web+mobile-app

all-agents = user+spider+bot

Historical data can be downloaded from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/

Comment: This is great!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found archive of page view statistics from 2007 to 2016 here: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/

At the bottom of the page they list several other sources covering various time periods.