# fetch Wikipedia view data of last 90 days in R

Tags: r, wiki

I tried to fetch view data of last 90 days from Wikipedia

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
library(ggplot2)


#download the last 90 days of PageView statistics:
page <- "USA"
raw_data <- getURL(paste("http://stats.grok.se/json/en/latest90/", page, sep=""))
data <- fromJSON(raw_data)
views <- data.frame(timestamp=paste(names(data$daily_views), " 12:00:00", sep=""), stringsAsFactors=F)
views$count <- data$daily_views
views$timestamp <- as.POSIXlt(views$timestamp) # Transform to POSIX datetime
views <- views[order(views$timestamp),]
```

Its producing error output :

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "count", value = list()) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What is the desired result? The page you refer to only holds `{"daily_views": {}, "project": "en", "month": "latest90", "rank": -1, "title": "USA"}`.

Comment: Using `page <- "Banana"` gives you a non-empty `data[['rank']]=1563` element, and an empty `daily_views` sublist element. Seems like there's something wrong on the server side, at this time. Or they forgot to update their documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to fetch daily_views data , but its not getting stored in R. Is there any change in location? How to fetch the daily_views data of any web page like Wikipedia ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40445113/1306662 ?